# Error adding foreign key to existing table in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, alter

I am adding a foreign key to an column in table in a mySQL DB:

```
alter table emp ADD FOREIGN KEY (porj) REFERENCES proj(projno)
```

The table with the existing column is emp, the column in emp is porj, and the foreign key resides in the table proj, column projno.
However I am getting the follwing error:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1046 - No database selected

I don't see anywhere in the syntax of the command where you need to add the DB name.

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Did you try <database>.emp in the above definition?  Where <database> is your dabase name.

Comment: See edit, i just had to select the DB in the project directory, but now I am getting the error mentioned above

Comment: Pls do not change a question to something completely different. If you have a new question, pls ask it properly, as a new question.

Comment: Your error is because you have not selected a default database, and you're trying to reference tables without qualifying them. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html